# Stacked bar chart from JSON file - seems to be ignoring a value

Tags: json, highcharts, stacked-chart

Pretty new to this stuff, so any help is greatly appreciated. To start off with, here is my JSON file's contents:

```
[
  {
    "drg": "NONSPECIFIC CEREBROVASCULAR DISORDERS W MCC",
    "approved": 124,
    "denied": 38
  },
  {
    "drg": "SEIZURES WO MCC",
    "approved": 138,
    "denied": 26
  },
  {
    "drg": "CHRONIC OBSTRUCTIVE PULMONARY DISEASE W CC",
    "approved": 352,
    "denied": 61
  },
  {
    "drg": "CHEST PAIN",
    "approved": 246,
    "denied": 44
  },
  {
    "drg": "TRANSIENT ISCHEMIA",
    "approved": 205,
    "denied": 37
  },
  {
    "drg": "OTHER DISORDERS OF NERVOUS SYSTEM W CC",
    "approved": 133,
    "denied": 23
  },
  {
    "drg": "DIABETES W MCC",
    "approved": 151,
    "denied": 27
  },
  {
    "drg": "CARDIAC ARRHYTHMIA CONDUCTION DISORDERS W CC",
    "approved": 336,
    "denied": 55
  },
  {
    "drg": "HYPERTENSION WO MCC",
    "approved": 177,
    "denied": 29
  },
  {
    "drg": "POISONING TOXIC EFFECTS OF DRUGS WO MCC",
    "approved": 144,
    "denied": 24
  }
]
```

My stacked bar chart, which worked fine with a CSV file, keeps ignoring the "denied" value. I suspect the issue has something to do with my formatting of the "processed_json.push()" portion of my code. It renders the approved value stacked on top of itself. Here is the script file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var processed_json = new Array();
        $.getJSON('/dashboard-test-data/denied-percentage-2015-chart.json', function(data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                processed_json.push([data[i].drg, data[i].approved, data[i].denied]);
            }
            $('#denied-percentage-2015-chart').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                credits: {
                    text: 'Vortext Analytics',
                    href: 'http://www.vortextanalytics.com'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Top 10 DRG by Denial Percentage 2015'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                },
                navigation: {
                    menuStyle: {
                        border: '1px solid #ddd',
                        boxShadow: 'none',
                    },
                    menuItemStyle: {
                        padding: '5px 1.5rem',
                    },
                    menuItemHoverStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f9',
                        color: '#666'
                    },
                    buttonOptions: {
                        height: 40,
                        width: 46,
                        symbolX: 23,
                        symbolY: 22,
                        x: 10,
                        y: -15,
                        symbolSize: 13,
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total Records'
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        },
                        formatter: function() {   
                            return (this.axis.series[1].yData[this.x] / this.total * 100).toPrecision(2) + '%';
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 0,
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    y: 22,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false,
                    reversed: true,
                },
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: {point.y:,0f} of {point.stackTotal:,0f}  <b>({point.percentage:.1f}%)</b><br />',
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                            style: {
                                textOutline: 'none',
                                fontWeight: 'normal',
                                fontSize: '9px'
                            }
                        },
                        pointWidth: 20,   
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'approved',
                    color: '#55B4E4',
                    data: processed_json,
                }, {
                    name: 'denied',
                    color: '#005079',
                    data: processed_json,
                }],
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is what the end product should produce (screen grab from my csv version):
[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcUso.png)

And here is what I'm getting from the JSON file: [incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm4tD.png)

Any assistance or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at highchart's [stacked bar chart example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked). For each series, `data` contains the array of values for that series.

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
}]
```

In your case, instead of creating the `processed_json` array of objects, you should create separate arrays containing each series' values.

Change the loop this way:

```
        var xAxis = []
            , approvedCount = []
            , deniedCount = []

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            xAxis.push(data[i].drg);
            approvedCount.push(data[i].approved);
            deniedCount.push(data[i].denied);
```

Then adapt the chart's instantiation accordingly:

```
// (...)
xAxis: {
    categories: xAxis
},
// (...)
            series: [{
                name: 'approved',
                color: '#55B4E4',
                data: approvedCount,
            }, {
                name: 'denied',
                color: '#005079',
                data: deniedCount,
            }],
// (...)
```